# Error de "invalid-input-response" con Google reCaptcha v3

Tags: recaptcha

estoy intentando implementar un captcha en mi web y algo que parecía sencillo me esta costando un poco.
Estoy usando Google recaptcha v3 y cada vez que envío el formulario me aparece el error:

** { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "invalid-input-response" }**

En mi index.html tengo mi script dentro del head asi:

```js
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
      document.getElementById("form-mail").submit();
    }
  </script>
```

... y luego mi formulario, con el campo oculto con la respuesta del captcha:

```html
<form id="form-mail" action="/assets/php/envio_mail.php" method="POST">

              <label for="name">Escribe tu nombre</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
              <label for="email">Tu dirección de email</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
              <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Tu mensaje" required></textarea>
              <!-- Campo oculto para almacenar la respuesta del reCAPTCHA -->
              <input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response">
              <button class="theme-btn-1 full-btn" data-sitekey="CLAVE_DE_SITIO_WEB" 
              data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit' name="submit">Enviar</button>
              
</form>
```

Y por último el PHP que procesa y envía el email:

```
        <?php
$secretKey = "CLAVE_SECRETA";
$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secretKey}&response={$response}");
$data = json_decode($verify);

if ($data->success) {
//proceso y envio mail
    } 
else {

        echo "Error: El reCAPTCHA no se validó correctamente.";
        var_dump($data); 
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
?>
```

Alguien me podría ayudar? Muchísimas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Doc oficial: `invalid-input-response -> The response parameter is invalid or malformed.` https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify